# Bash file gam: command not found

Tags: bash, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

I'm trying to write a bash file which contains several [gam](https://github.com/GAM-team/GAM/wiki/) - commands which are used to add google calendars to employee google accounts. Unfortunately gam commands only allow to add one calendar at a time. The file is executable at first but it won't execute the gam - commands although gam is already installed on my mac. How can I make this file accept these commands.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo Type user email where calendars needs to be added:

read -p 'User email: ' usermail

gam user usermail add calendar xxxxx@group.calendar.google.com selected false
```

I already tried changing the bash file permissions.

Comment: If you run the `gam` command line from the prompt, what does it say then? If that works, how are you running the bash script? Could it be that you run it via `crontab` or similar?

Comment: The gam command works in the terminal. I used chmod +x -script- and made it executable from the desktop via the terminal (https://www.macinstruct.com/tutorials/how-to-make-a-bash-script-executable-on-a-mac/)

Comment: Ok, and are you also running the bash script from the same prompt or are you running it in some other way?

Comment: A new terminal window opens when i execute the bash file. It looks like this terminal window "has no idea" gam is already installed

Comment: That's odd. In the terminal where `gam` is still working, do `which gam` to find the full path to `gam`. Replace `gam` in your script with that path.

Comment: OMG ! It worked ! Thanks ! But now my user input isn't working anymore :(

`User email: test@domain.com

ERROR: User usermail@domain.com: invalid_grant: Invalid email or User ID`

Comment: :-) You're welcome! Unfortunately, I know nothing about the `gam` tool itself so I can't say why the grant is failing, sorry.

Comment: 1) are you still prompted to enter user email? 2) perhaps you need `gam user "$usermail" add ...`

Comment: @jhnc yep fixed my problem -  "$" was missing :D

Answer (score 0):

```bash
~/bin/gam/gam user usermail add calendar xxxxx@group.calendar.google.com selected false
```

Basicly use **~/bin/gam/gam** instead of just **gam** in your script.